# Using print statement while lazily loading childs in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Customer and Phone class with one to many association with lazy set to true.

I load the Customer object with id as **'101'** using

```
Customer cust = (Customer) session.get(Customer.class, 1); -- (1)
cust.getPhoneList();                                       -- (2)
System.out.println(cust.getPhoneList());                   -- (3)
```

At point (1), I don't have List of phones since they are lazily loaded.

At point (2), I don't have List of phones and no database call is made.

At point (3) or if point (2) is replaced with point (3),database call is made that returns list of phone numbers.I always thought that database call is made to return phone numbers only if i do some operation with the list. For e.g., `cust.getPhoneList().size()` or iterating over it.

I didn't get why using print statement made the database call?

Comment: Because the println() method calls the toString() method , and in order to call the toString() method the object must be retrieved from the database =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you **do** an operation on the list.

```
 System.out.println(cust.getPhoneList());
```

is done as

```
 System.out.println(cust.getPhoneList().toString());
```

Comment: IMO, that doesn't answer the question. He could still ask: *"And why does the `toString()` method make a database call?"*. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, `System.out.println(Object x)` calls `String.valueOf(x)`, witch then does:

```
 return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
```

In the end, you are invoking an operation, the `toString()` method.

Since your list is persisted by Hibernate, it is a `PersistentList` when retrieved from the Database. And here it is, `PersistentList`'s implementation of the `toString()` method:

```
public String toString() {
    read();
    return list.toString();
}
```

You see that the first call is `read()`, witch is the method that forces a list initialization.

Obviously, for the initialization to occur, you have to go to the database retrieve all the data. That triggered the database call.